# UserDefaults array continously returns nil

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an two arrays, named `textMessages` and `sendersMessages`.
When my view loads, I want to read those arrays and create a new label for each message, and change it's color depending on the value stored in `sendersMessages`.

Here is my ViewController code:

```
class ConversationViewController: UIViewController {

    ///UserDefaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Synchronise NSUserDefaults
        defaults.synchronize()

        //Load previous messages
        let nMessages: Int = defaults.integer(forKey: "numberOfMessages")
        let arrayOfMessages = defaults.array(forKey: "textMessages")
        let arrayOfSenders = defaults.array(forKey: "sendersMessages")

        var i = 1
        for i in 0...nMessages {
            let sender: String? = (arrayOfSenders?[i] as? String)
            let text: String? = (arrayOfMessages?[i] as? String)
            print("\(String(describing: sender)) sent the message: \(String(describing: text)) ; i = \(i)")
            if text != nil {
                if sender != nil {
                    displayNewMessage(text: text!, sentBy: sender!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `displayNewMessage()` function calls the `sendMessage()` (see code below) and creates a new label, but does not read or modify the UserDefaults.

Here is the function that I use to save the messages:

```
func sendMessage(text: String, sentBy: String, time: Double){
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var n = defaults.integer(forKey: "numberOfMessages")
    var sentByArray = defaults.array(forKey: "sendersMessages")
    var textArray = defaults.array(forKey: "textMessages")

    sentByArray?.append(sentBy)
    textArray?.append(text)
    n = n + 1

    defaults.set(sentByArray, forKey: "sendersMessages")
    defaults.set(textArray, forKey: "textMessages")
    defaults.set(n, forKey: "numberOfMessages")

    //Synchronise NSUserDefaults
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

As you can see, I use two arrays (one to store the sender and the other to store the text) and an Int to know how many messages were sent.

Can someone please explain to me why the console prints the following

```
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 0
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 1
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 2
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 3
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 4
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 5
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 6
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 7
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 8
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 9
nil sent the message: nil ; i = 10
```

and not the content of the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sendMessage` code never sets any values for the arrays due to the optionals being `nil`.

You need:

```
func sendMessage(text: String, sentBy: String, time: Double){
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var n = defaults.integer(forKey: "numberOfMessages")
    var sentByArray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "sendersMessages") ?? []
    var textArray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "textMessages") ?? []

    sentByArray.append(sentBy)
    textArray.append(text)
    n = n + 1

    defaults.set(sentByArray, forKey: "sendersMessages")
    defaults.set(textArray, forKey: "textMessages")
    defaults.set(n, forKey: "numberOfMessages")
}
```

And note that you do not need to call `synchronize`, especially just before reading values like in your `viewDidLoad` method.

And you should update `viewDidLoad` as well:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Load previous messages
    let nMessages: Int = defaults.integer(forKey: "numberOfMessages")
    let arrayOfMessages = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "textMessages") ?? []
    let arrayOfSenders = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "sendersMessages") ?? []

    for i in 0..<nMessages {
        let sender = arrayOfSenders[i]
        let text = arrayOfMessages[i]
        print("\(sender) sent the message: \(text) ; i = \(i)")
        displayNewMessage(text: text!, sentBy: sender!)
    }
}
```

And you really don't need to store the number of messages. Just look at the number of objects in the arrays.

Something else to consider - `UserDefaults` is not the place to store your app's data. And you should have a `struct` that represents each instance of your data. Make the `struct` codable and write the (single) array of data to a file. All of this is left as an exercise for the reader since it is well beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Unfortunately, I still have an error when running the app: my line `let sender: String? = (arrayOfSenders?[i] as? String)` gets the following error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`. What should I do?

Comment: 1. That line should be changed as I show in my answer. 2. Your `UserDefaults` are out of whack due to your earlier bug. Delete the app (from the device/simulator) and start again with clean user defaults and the updated code.